# How can I install a package using easy_install from a package on the local host?

Tags: python, easy-install

I am trying to install Python packages using easy_install from a local directory.

The reason I am doing this is because of network/IT issues.

I have a workstation (Ubuntu) that can access easy_install's repositories on the Internet.  I can install things without any problems.

We have a lab network that is closed off to the Internet.  I have an Ubuntu VM on this lab network.  I cannot use easy_install (or pip) to install anything because it is blocked off from the repositories.  I need to install some Python packages so I need to work around this limitation.

The way I got around this limitation for pip was to do a "pip download" of a package, then SCP the package file to the VM in the lab network and do a "pip install" of the package file.

I am trying to do this with easy_install.   I was able to download the easy_install package by issuing this command

```
    > easy_install -q --editable --build-directory . <package name>
```

For example, suppose I wanted to install pip using easy_install.  I have the pip directory after downloading the source code thru easy_install.  I can tar the pip directory and SCP it over to the VM.  Is there a way to tell easy_install on the VM to install using the files from the pip directory rather than try to install via the external repository?

I have searched for a similar question to this using the easy_install tag but I don't see anything so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: It may work but you would need to download every dependency one by one. I would suggest finding another solution than this one.

Comment: An option could be to tunnel your connection to pypi via SSH, have a look at the manpage for the `-D` and `-R` options.

Answer (score 0):

[devpi-server](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/quickstart-pypimirror.html) is a caching PyPI proxy. If you use it to install packages on one host, it will forward requests to https://pypi.python.org/pypi, and save everything it downloads. Then you copy over a tarball of `~/.devpi` to another host, launch the server, and have `devpi-server` serve up the cached files.

Host 1 (online):

```
$ easy_install --user devpi-server
$ devpi-server --start
$ easy_install --user -i http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/ Django
```

Copy `~/.devpi` from Host 1 to Host 2

Somehow you’ll also need to copy `devpi-server` over to the offline box too. It has quite a few dependencies. Maybe to bootstrap you could create a basic VM, run `easy_install --user devpi-server`, then tar up `~/.local` and copy it over?

Host 2 (no internet):

```
$ devpi-server --start
$ easy_install --user -i http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/ Django
# Success!
```

Comment: andrewdotn, I issued the 3 commands you listed for Host 1.

When I issue the 3rd command, using a different directory location: "$ easy_install --user -i http://localhost:3141/root/tools/devpi/ pip" ... easy_install instead installed pip at /root/.local/bin.  Is the directory location specified after localhost the location you want to place the installation?

Comment: @SQA777 Normally you install python packages from the internet to `~/.local`. This setup adds a cache in the middle at `~/tools/devpi`. The install files will be downloaded from the internet to `~/tools/devpi` on one machine, and then later you can install packages from that install file cache to `~/local` on a machine without internet access.